# Title Attribute Selector for 1 Menu Item

Tags: css, wordpress, attributes

I am working on this website: http://box5155.temp.domains/~grownows/

In the top menu bar, I want "Get In Touch" to have the following CSS working on it so it stands out more:

```
font-size: 120%;
text-transform: none;
```

I also want a green border box around it but I haven't even figured that out yet lol.

So I've tried just doing these in CSS but those didn't work (the only thing that strangely worked is changing the font to Escafina.) I did use !important on the font-size and text-transform but that didn't work.

```
.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-
50.menu-item-link { 
   font-size: 120%;
   font-family: 'Escafina';
   text-transform: none;
   color: blue;
}

#menu-item-50 {
text-transform: none;
font-size: 120%;
}
```

So then I gave the "get in touch" the title attribute "getintouch" and tried this:

```
.a[target="getintouch"] { 
text-transform: none;
font-size: 120%;
}
```

Now I am stuck.  I tried without a "." selector before the a too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?? Also, the link show a page without the "Get In Touch" (in fact without the top menu bar).

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla are you sure? That is so weird. The homepage should have that top menu bar uh ohhh

Comment: @Emigriff what I'm seeing is a coming soon page. I think the site may only be visible if you are logged in.

Comment: Maybe is what @BarryMode says. How about add to your question your HTML and CSS relevant code?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla thanks so much for talking a look. I couldn't get the code to format correctly to paste in here. I just turned off the 'coming soon' thing so you may be able to see it? Otherwise I'll have to ask the question again after I turn this live I guess. Thanks so much

Comment: cc @BarryMode also see above

Comment: I'm not familiar with wordpress, but do you have access to the CSS file? If you do, you can add this rule `#menu-item-50 { border: 3px solid #000; }`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I tested it:

```
li#menu-item-50.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-50.menu-item-link a {
  font-size: 120%;
  text-transform: none;
  border: 1px solid #b4d447;
  padding: 0 17px !important;
  max-height: 34px;
}
```